# Sales order observer event issue

Tags: event-observer, magento-1

This is my observer:

```
public function changeStatus(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $getOrder =  Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getId());
        $OldOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($getOrder->getData('relation_parent_id'));
        $OldOrder->setState('mystatushere', true)->save();

    }
```

I used this event: `sales_order_save_before` or `sales_order_save_after`. I know the code is not optimized, so please don't blame me :D . What I want to achieve is to change the parent order status. 
I edit an order, make some modification and save it. A new order is created with `increment-id-1` and when it this one is save I want to change the status of its parent order.

But I 'm receiving this:
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on boolean in app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Observer.php:46.` Any idea why ? thx

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because `$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();` is not working.

**UPDATE:**

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
if(!$order->getId()){
    $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW, true);
}
```

**OR :**

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    if(!$order->getId()):
      $orderModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getId());
       $orderModel->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW, true);
       $orderModel->setId($order->getId());
       $orderModel->save();
    endif;
```

Comment: If I do an echo `$order->getId()` I got the right id, so it works I also get the parent_id from `$getOrder->getData('relation_parent_id')`.

Comment: this line ` $OldOrder->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true)->save()` is the problem

Comment: better to use `sales_order_place_after` because order is not saved in `sales_order_save_after`

Comment: and no need to write save();

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: no errors this time, but the parent order didn't change its status, its still the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53122/discussion-between-borncoder-and-chester).